# Creating 301 redirects from asp.net website to another

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, http-status-code-301

I have a website which i'm planning to close down and replace with another with a different domain, how can i go about setting up 301 redirects from specific pages on my old site to the relevant pages on my new one?

I've had a look into the IIS Url Rewrite Module, but wasn't able to figure it out. Help please?

I've tried this

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirects to new domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://domain.com/" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But nothing happens when navigation to the homepage

Answer (score 0):

You can update your web.config with routing rules like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirects to new domain" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="olddomain.net" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newdomain.com/{R:0}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: you have http:// in you condition pattern for HTTP_HOST, you should have just a domain name, like "domain.com", no http or https since that's not part of the host name.